# TurtleBot 2i Catkin_Make gives: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'catkin_pkg.terminal_color'

Tags: python, linux, ros, catkin

I am currently working with TurtleBot 2i, and I am just trying to install the GitHub repository.

I followed this link in order to install:

https://github.com/Interbotix/turtlebot2i/wiki/Full-Build-Instructions

Because I have previously installed Anaconda and installed some packages with Anaconda, I have removed:

```
export PATH="/home/sean/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

from my .bashrc file.

The problem I have is that when I `catkin_make` my TurtleBot 2i folder, it gives me the following error:

```
[ 11%] Built target _turtlebot2i_block_manipulation_generate_messages_check_deps_PickAndPlaceResult
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/geneus/cmake/../../../lib/geneus/gen_eus.py", line 39, in <module>
    import geneus
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geneus/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from . geneus_main import *
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geneus/geneus_main.py", line 43, in <module>
    from catkin import terminal_color
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/terminal_color.py", line 2, in <module>
    from catkin_pkg.terminal_color import *  # noqa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'catkin_pkg.terminal_color'
```

I typed:

```
dpkg -L python-catkin-pkg-modules
```

And this is what it gives me:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/python-catkin-pkg-modules
/usr/share/doc/python-catkin-pkg-modules/copyright
/usr/share/doc/python-catkin-pkg-modules/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/topological_order.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/metapackage.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/tool_detection.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/terminal_color.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/changelog_generator.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cmake.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/changelog_generator_vcs.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/templates
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/templates/CMakeLists.txt.in
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/templates/package.xml.in
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/templates/metapackage.cmake.in
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/python_setup.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/group_dependency.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package_templates.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/workspace_vcs.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/group_membership.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/packages.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/changelog.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/prepare_release.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/create_pkg.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/test_changelog.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/generate_changelog.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/tag_changelog.py 
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/find_pkg.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/package_version.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package_version.py 
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/condition.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/rospack.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/workspaces.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg_modules-0.4.8.egg-info
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg_modules-0.4.8.egg-info/top_level.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg_modules-0.4.8.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg_modules-0.4.8.egg-info/PKG-INFO
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg_modules-0.4.8.egg-info/requires.txt
```

I think this is some sort of `catkin_pkg` version problem, but I cannot figure out what the problem is.

I have tried to uninstall and install `catkin_pkg` through pip, but both failed.

Is there any way to solve this terminal_color error?

The output of `env | grep PATH; env | grep ROS`is the following:

```
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/sean/turtlebot2i/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/sean/turtlebot2i/devel/lib:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu  
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
PATH=/home/sean/turtlebot2i/devel/bin:/opt/ros/kinetic/bin:/home/sean/bin:/home/sean/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin    
MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
PYTHONPATH=/home/sean/turtlebot2i/devel/lib/python3/dist-packages:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/sean/turtlebot2i/devel/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/sean/turtlebot2i/devel:/opt/ros/kinetic
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/sean/turtlebot2i/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_VERSION=1
ROS_HOSTNAME=sean-Lenovo-ideapad-Y700-17ISK
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/sean/turtlebot2i/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_DISTRO=kinetic
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros
```

Comment: I assume you followed [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/56873/problem-with-catkin_make/) instruction? Also, what does `ls -l $(which python)` gives you?

Comment: It gives me this: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Nov 23  2017 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7

Comment: I do not know if this is the problem but my which python command does not give an existing directory.

Comment: It sounds that your environment is tainted, but hard to say. Please add the output of the following command to your question: `env | grep PATH; env | grep ROS`

Comment: Can you try deleting the `build` and `devel` folders of your `turtlebot2i` workspace and rebuilding? From the `PYTHONPATH` it seems like it was initially compiled with Python 3.